# Text in a textView

Tags: android

I have a second activity that queries an online database and I want to set text of the TextView but I can't. When I start the application the TextView is empty.

This is the code of the second activity:

```
 public class sendQuery extends main  {
/////////// Public method to send Query ///////////
public static String send(String query, Activity sendQuery) {
    String result = "0";
    InputStream is = null;
    String weekDayVal=null;
    String provola=null;
    //the query to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> querySend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    querySend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("querySend",query));

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://locali.altervista.org/php/locali.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(querySend));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        try{
            TextView text = (TextView) sendQuery.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
            JSONArray weekDetails = new JSONArray ( result); // Your response string
            for(int index=0;index < 1/*weekDetails.length()*/;index++)
            {
            JSONObject tempWeekDetail = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
            weekDayVal = tempWeekDetail.getString("Lunedi");// Value for Monday
            //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
            Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+weekDayVal);
            JSONObject provino = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
            provola = provino.getString("Martedi");// Value for Monday
            //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
            Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+provola);
            text.setText(provola);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {


            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result: "+e.toString());
    }

    Log.i("SendQUERY", result);
    return result;
}
}
```

The problem is in a second activity, here

```
 TextView text = (TextView) sendQuery.findViewById(R.id.textView10); 
 text.setText(provola);
```

Comment: Are you getting something from the Query?

Comment: Try this :  TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity if I write that.

Comment: Yes I get from the query

Comment: If you set some text for the TextView in the XML layout can you see the text? Maybe the TextView is hidden somewhere/somehow

Comment: but in logcat I see the text with this comand Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+provola);

Comment: You see text from your response, but you don't see it in the TextView, so maybe the TextView is somehow hidden, try setting some default text for the TextView in xml and see if you can see it. Or, after you set text call `Log.i("Text", text.getText());` and see if the text has been correctly set. If it has you need to find out why the TextView isn't visible.

Comment: The text is visible because i see only " text for textview"

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "test";
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10); 
text.setText(s);
```

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity, why?

Comment: delete static ,because you cant use static method in non static

Comment: in the main activity then I have this error: Can not make a static reference to the non-static method send (String) from the type sendQuery

Answer (score 0):

The root issue is that you're trying to access class instance members via a static method. The static method could be called on any of the class instances or even before any instances exist. So either change the send() method to be non-static by removing the static keyword or do the following.

Change your send method to accept a sendQuery class type for the confusingly named second parameter instead of an Activty type:

```
public static String send(String query, sendQuery sendQuery) {
```

Define your text instance as a public member of the sendQuery activity class with

```
public TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
```

then access it in the static send() method with

```
sendQuery.text.setText(provola);
```

Comment: For some helpful information on static vs instance, check out the long answer on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/211137/why-can-static-methods-only-use-static-data .

Comment: I have an error on public TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10): Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type 
  Activity
 - Illegal modifier for the variable text; only final is permitted

Comment: That line should be outside of the static send() method. In other words, right under the 'public class sendQuery extends main  {' line.

Comment: In this way, but I have no errors in the TextView is not present the value "provola".

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but it sounds like it's now having problems with the scope of the provola variable. If you didn;t move it, that variable is local to the method and should be visible.